# Accessing class attributes mutually in composition python

Tags: python, python-2.7, composition

Is it bad practice to access the 'parent' object's attributes when using composition?

I have a class where I need to have a software that runs depending on a specific file format. At this point only a few formats will be supported and others can be added later. The idea is to make adding the new formats as easy and structured as possible. Depending on the software, the methods should be named the same, but they do not follow the same steps.

All pieces of software will return an output, based on the parameters given in an .ini file and actions will be executed one after another using the sections of the ini file as classes of `ConfigSection`.

```python
class ConfigSection(object):
    def __init__(self,parameters,software=None):
        self.parameters = parameters
        self.software = software

    def call_software(self,name):
        self.software = get_softwate(name,self)
        self.software.setup()
        self.software.run()

    def get_output(self):
        pass

    def do_actions(self):
        pass

def get_software(name,section):
    # Find right software
    # Return subclass of Software with given parameters

class Software(object):
    def __init__(self,section):
        self.section = section

    def setup(self):
        # Get the necessary info from 'section'

    def run(self):
        parameters = self.section.parameters

class A(Software):
    def __init__(self,section):
        self.section = section

    def setup(self):
        parameters = self.section.parameters
        # Read the necessary parameters for this software and prepare them
        # to be used in run

    def run(self,parameters):
        # Build command using the parameters
```

Comment: It's a little unclear what you're asking.  Could you maybe explain which part of the code you provided might be bad, and write a little about why it would be bad?  In general, there's nothing wrong with using attributes from a Parent class: the whole point of inheritance is to make those attributes available.

Comment: Constantly using the attributes of the `ConfigSection` class through the `A` class. I'm not sure whether the use of composition is preferred when the added class (`A` in this case)  does not depend on `ConfigSection`. Just a bit confused on the right use of composition.